# How can I display stats like death count using titles?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a dungeon-crawler adventure map, and at the end I would like the system to tell the player, either within the chat or on screen (using `/title`) these criteria:

- Number of deaths
- Number of rooms entered (out of X)
- Number of mobs killed
- Number of times fell in lava/from a high place

Things like that. I know that there's a way so that the player can press tab or have it displayed on the right of the screen, but I would like it so it's kind of a credits thing.

Comment: Is your question just how to display a death count, or how to display all of those things? What have you tried so far and what are you stuck on?

Comment: As far as I know, you can only get the death count, not the death cause.

Comment: I think you can get the cause as a subtype of the death stat. I can't check for sure right now, though.

Comment: @colorfusion I'm asking the command to have the death cout/other counts (as scoreboard stats) displayed in either the chat (Ex. /say @a deathCount) or as a title (/title deathCount)

Comment: @SweetDelight So, if I'm understanding right, you already have the objectives set up, and just want to know how to say them into chat/a title?

Comment: Okay, just checked and I guess I'm wrong; it doesn't seem like you're able to track different types of deaths.  You can track which mob has killed you though with `stat.entityKilledBy`.

Comment: @colorfusion That's exactly correct.

Answer (score 2):

As you already have the objectives set up and working, it's fairly simple to output them. You'll need to use the JSON format to get the player's score, like this:

```
["",{"score":{"name":"*","objective":"ObjectiveName"}}]
```

Where ObjectiveName is the name of the objective you want to get the player's value of.

`/title` already accepts JSON data, so all you need to do is:

```
/title @p title ["",{"score":{"name":"*","objective":"ObjectiveName"}}]
```

`/say` doesn't accept the JSON format, so you should use `/tellraw` instead, which does:

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"score":{"name":"*","objective":"ObjectiveName"}}]
```

If you want it as part of a sentence, you could change the JSON part to something like:

```
["You have died ",{"score":{"name":"*","objective":"ObjectiveName"}}, " times."]
```

Comment: Can you add how one would you go about embedding the score into a sentence, like: "You died X times."? I assume it's just `["You died ",{...}," times."]`?

Comment: @MrLemon Yep, that's how you do it. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @colorfusion Thank you so much! You're a lifesaver.